# Does LOGITECH wireless keyboard and mouse works with Raspberry Pi3?

Tags: pi-2

I'm planning to buy Raspberry Pi 3. And my main purpose is to connect it to display monitors that are present in my university library. They have VGA and USB ports to connect to other devices.

I like to install Windows 10 iot in Rpi3. And connect to those display monitors to use it as a system. So im thinking to use wireless keyboard and mouse with Rpi3. Does it work?

Anyone tried wirless sets with Rpi3?

And I need suggestions on which is better in OS? Linux OS or Windows10 ioT for using Rpi3.

Final question: Can I use Seagate 1TB hard drive for storing my files when I'm using Rpi3 as monitor or laptop?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks! Also note that parts of your question are highly subjective, e.g. which OS is *better*, which makes that hard to answer in an objective way.

Answer (score 2):

I already have a Logitech keyboard+mouse (K400 Plus) with a usb dongle working on my Raspberry Pi 3 without any configuration. Just plugged and working.

I suggest you to install Linux on Raspberry Pi. In my opinion is better. But is just my opinion. :)

For first starting you will need a monitor and the keyboard, but after install an ssh server you will no need longer the keyboard. And after installing a Vnc server the monitor is not needed anymore.

And for your last question. Yes, you can plug whatever you need. A 1TB Seagate hard disk is ok if you plug it by usb.

Comment: I can report that the Logitech K400 also works with LibreELEC/Kodi and RetroCade.

Answer (score 0):

copied this post I made on another forum here, as it should help anyone with a logitech keyboard/mouse not connecting.
Note:  I tried to get this working with a generic bluetooth adapter and it would only pick up one device you need the LOGITECH UNIFYING RECIEVER!

just posting this in case anyone is having trouble getting Logitech Bluetooth keyboards working with a raspberry pi. If you google you will come across solaar, it's a piece of software that takes the place of the logitech option software and allows you to pair your devices to a logitech unifying reciever. Just sudo apt-get install solaar to get it and do a reboot.

It should add a system tray icon and if you click on that it should list the unifying reciever, some keyboard will pair automatically, unfortunately my K850 didn't however I found a neat little workaround to share which is the purpose of this post.

First of all whenever the software asks you to turn off and on your device you have to pull the batteries on the keyboard but the mouse has an on off switch. Secondly before you switch it on and off make sure the button you are selecting is the one you want to pair on.

Now if yours isn't showing up or pairing on the rasperry pi (raspbian) or other linux desktop with solaar there is a way round it. Unplug the unifying reciever, plug it into a windows PC then use the logitech options software and do the switch on and off to pair it (you also have to hit and hold one of the select buttons until it blinks fast. Then unplug the logitech unifying reciever again and plug it back into your raspberry pi, it should now list the K850 keyboard and triathlon mouse!! It seems that the unifying reciever stores the paired devices! Hope this helps with anyone struggling to get it working. I would imagine it might be the same with other keyboards. FYI have tried this out on Ubuntu desktop and had the same issue, this fixed it as well!